# Round trip logging in entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, logging, objectcontext

I know this is possible in Linq-to-Sql, is it possible to automatically log all queries made through a particular ObjectContext in entity framework?  In particular, I'm interested in the number of queries that are run in the lifetime of the ObjectContext.

Comment: Which DBMS and Data Provider are you using?

Comment: What are you talking about: Entity Framework and thus Linq-to-Entities, or Linq-to-SQL? Two pretty different technologies, really!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ObjectQuery.ToTraceString or look into [Jaroslaw Kowalski's tracing and caching provider](http://blogs.msdn.com/jkowalski/archive/2009/06/11/tracing-and-caching-in-entity-framework-available-on-msdn-code-gallery.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're looking for something quick and easy to implement, rather than having to insert log statements or other code into all of your query routines.  I don't know of a way to do this with just an instance of ObjectContext but there may be a way to do it through your data provider.  For example if you happen to be using Devart for Oracle, you can handle the Devart.Common.DbMonitor.TraceEvent event of Devart.Common.DbMonitor.